# redirect with same address but paste something on the end using grease script

Tags: redirect, greasemonkey

(First h's omitted in this question purposefully to save links allowed)

ok so i was browsing crunchyroll vids and noticed it naturally goes to 480 whenever i click a video. crunchyroll's video player seems to be the only one that ever lags on this setting so i immediately click the "SD" button to go to "standard" which refreshes the page and places "?p360=1" on the end of the address i was at previously... i.e:

### ttp://www.crunchyroll.com/rwby/episode-4-lessons-learned-687889

### is redirected to=

**ttp://www.crunchyroll.com/rwby/episode-4-lessons-learned-687889?p360=1**

notice the thing at the "?p360=1" at the end is the only difference of these addresses?
so i googled redirecting one webpage to another and came across the stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14576139/5760879) that was answered with something so similar to what i needed it just begs to ask:

can i do this answer but instead of

redirectToPage("ttp://www.youtube.com/", "ttp://www.google.com");

can i get it to act like

redirectToPage("***Whatever address i was on****", "***Whatever address i was on****?p360=1");

this way i can just change the 
@match      http://*/*

to

@match      ttp://www.crunchyroll.com/(asterisk)/(asterisk)

-asterisks were being ignored in preview for some derp reason-

the goal is to redirect all crunchyroll videos to its "sd" quality setting webpage if possible - if not doable this way perhaps another way?

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry that i may have wasted anyone's time but do not delete this please as i am sure i am not the only one who could find this useful (took me about 30-40 minutes of lazily doing searches to find all i needed to make this!!!). I have done some more lurking, tinkered around a bit, and finally found a way! Also i have made this script downloadable on my [GREASY FORK](https://greasyfork.org/en/users/13772-endorakai)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Crunchyroll Resolution Enforcement
// @namespace  https://greasyfork.org/en/users/13772-endorakai
// @version    1.0
// @description  Sets Crunchyroll Resolution To Preferred Resolution
// @include      http://www.crunchyroll.com/*/*episode*
// @exclude      http://www.crunchyroll.com/*/*?p360=1
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.location.replace (window.location.href + "?p360=1");

//you can change the resolutions by going to "?p360=1" on line 11
//and changing it to:
//480 res = "?p480=1"
//720 res = "?p720=1" <<<---REQUIRES THEIR MEMBERSHIP/LOGGED IN
//1080 res= "?p1080=1" <<<---REQUIRES THEIR MEMBERSHIP/LOGGED IN
//***MUST ALSO CHANGE YOUR EXCLUDE THE SAME WAY SO YOU DONT 
//***KEEP LOOPING THE PAGE:
//***simply change the *?p360=1 to the same paste you used to edit line 11
```